# Hoare triple notation

Tags: coq

The recent [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129063/set-theory-notation-with-whitespaces-and-curly-braces-in-coq) of set notations re-motivates me to ask if anybody (Tej?) has a clever idea for getting Coq to accept a standard notation for Hoare triples -- something like this:

```
Notation "{ P }  c  { Q }" :=
  (hoare_triple P c Q) 
  (at level 0, P at level 99, c at level 99, Q at level 99) 
  : Hoare_scope.
```

Coq's error is "Error: A notation must include at least one symbol."  Which I don't understand in light of the fact that

```
Notation "{ x }" := (x) (at level 0, x at level 99).
```

does work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using another symbol somewhere to make this parseable. I've seen Adam Chlipala use `Notation "{{ P }}  c  {{ Q }}"` for example. You can also define `{ P }  c  { Q }` as a printing-only notation, although I imagine that's less useful and potentially confusing to new users.

Curly braces are special; some of the ways they're special are [documented in the manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#syntax-of-notations) (scroll down to the third note), but I confess I don't really understand that note beyond "here be dragons, ask Hugo Herbelin".

I can tell you mechanically why you're getting the error while "{ x }" works:

- curly braces don't count as symbols, because of a special `remove_curly_brackets` function
- if the notation is already in the parsing table, it doesn't need to include new symbols

This is checked in [metasyntax.ml](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/8e675d70ad1f60cbbf9f1e630ce6dee61347c7ca/vernac/metasyntax.ml#L1243-L1246), which I found by looking for how the error message is thrown. You can also confirm what the Coq grammar is using `Print Grammar constr` (this is also how you figure out what level everything actually is).

Comment: Thanks -- that's super helpful.  Software Foundations uses {{P}}c{{Q}} currently, and from this exchange it appears this is a local optimum.  My compromise is that when I typeset them in HTML I move them closer together so they look a bit like a blackboard-bold single brace.